# Gulp webpack production mode causes issue with vue updating in iOS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, gulp, babeljs

I'm creating a page that is a collection of products. When a user clicks on the image of one of the products, a detailed version of that product slides in.

I'm using vue to update the src of the images as well as the product ID depending on which product is clicked. I'm finding that sometimes — only on iOS phones, and only when I run webpack in production mode — the HTML isn't redrawn with the new image `src` attribute or product ID. A console log does show it's updating my variable but vue isn't firing the redraw.

My products grid is set up like this:

```
<div v-for="product in products.items" class="column">
    <div v-on:click="open(product)" :class="[{'soldout' : (product.inventoryCount == 0)},'image']">
        <img :src="product.images[0].src" :alt="product.images[0].alt">
    </div>
</div>
```

My detailed section looks like this:

```
<div v-for="image in productImages" :key="image.src" class="slide">
    <img :src="image.src" :alt="image.alt">
    <button class="button" v-on:click="addToCart" :data-id="productID">Add to Cart</button>
</div>
```

My function to update the vue variables looks like this:

```
open(product) {
    this.productImages = product.images;
    this.productID = product.variantId;
}
```

My gulp task to run webpack looks like this:

```
.pipe(webpack({
    mode: `${mode}`,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ]
}))
```

And I use different gulp tasks to switch between development or production mode.

As far as I can tell it works no problem while I'm in development mode but as soon as I switch to production mode is when I notice the issue. If I do a console log of `this.productImages` or `this.productID` they are both updating with the correct information but neither the `<img :src="image.src" :alt="image.alt">` nor the `<button class="button" v-on:click="addToCart" :data-id="productID">Add to Cart</button>` gets updated.

The weird thing is that it seems to only happen on iPhones and it's completely random depending on refreshing. Sometimes it takes me several page refreshing to see it break and sometimes it's very consistent.

It also seems different depending on the phone. My coworkers phone has the issue almost every refresh but my phone takes several before I see it. Has anyone else dealt with an issue like this or have any idea what might be causing it?